# Check if timestamp older than 30 seconds

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to determine if a timestamp is older than 30 seconds, but for some reason it is coming back as older than 30 seconds when it hasn't even been a couple seconds.

Example: https://ideone.com/KLIIBz

```
public static Boolean cooldown(int id) {

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -secondsAgo);
    long timeAgo = now.getTimeInMillis();
    if ( cooldown.containsKey(id) ) {

        System.out.println(cooldown.get(id) + " | " + timeAgo);

        // Stored timestamp always older than timeAgo
        if ( cooldown.get(id) < timeAgo ) {

            cooldown.remove(id);

        } else {

            // This code should be executed, as I am running the function one after another from same UUID not even a second or two apart.
            return false;

        }

    }

    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cooldown.put(id, now.getTimeInMillis());

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is not that, e.g. what is `target`, and how do you call `cooldown()`?

Comment: All that code is really redundant. Only issue is why the timestamp is coming back older than it is.

Comment: If the rest of the code is very redundant, then creating a minimal example should be easy, right?

Comment: The millis `1491192189486` from the first line of value `timeAgo` is `2017-04-02 21:03:09.486 PDT`, *same as* the log time of `21:03:09`, i.e. *not* offset by -30 seconds. Are you ***sure*** the value of `secondsAgo` is `30`, at the time the code is executed, and not still the initial value of `0`? Try changing declaration to `private static final int secondsAgo = 30;`.

Comment: See updated online example. `secondsAgo` is established with the class. So yes I am sure it is 30. I'm not sure how to store a timestamp (whatever type) and check if it is 30 seconds old as this doesn't work. I made this from various examples here subtracting time to get a time go.

Comment: Rather than `Calendar` you are probably better off using the date and time classes in Java 8 if you can: `Instant` and `Duration`; or just `System.currentTimeMillis()` as ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ suggests in an answer.

Comment: I take it that `cooldown` is a map? What is the type of the value you get from there? I was thinking if it was `Integer`, this would explain why the timestamp appears to be very old.

Comment: Just looked at your code on Ideone in the link. In that code, no instance of your class `Ideone` is ever created. So `secondsAgo` is never set to 30. @Andreas is right in his suspicion.

Comment: When I asked if you're **sure** the value of `secondsAgo` is `30`, you said yes, without even checking. I asked, because that was the only cause I could see that would give the result displayed, so I was fairly certain it was `0`, and as it turns out, I was right. Next time, **verify**, e.g. using a **debugger**. If you don't know how to debug, now is a great time to learn. It is an essential skill for a programmer. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration
.between( then , Instant.now() )
.toNanos()
>
Duration
.ofSeconds( 30 )
.toNanos()
```

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
…
Instant stop = Instant.now();
```

Capture the span of time in between the start and stop as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Represent your limit of 30 seconds.

```
Duration limit = Duration.ofSeconds( 30 );
```

Compare by calling the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) method of [`Duration::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#compareTo-java.time.Duration-).

```
Boolean exceededLimit = ( duration.compareTo( limit ) > 0 );
```

By the way, having a collection and a method both named `cooldown` is not helpful.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Rather than `compareTo()` I think I’d consider just `duration.getSeconds() < secondsAgo` (where `secondsAgo` must be 30). Of course, declaring `limit` a `Duration` tells the reader that this is what it is, so there are pros and cons. And it’s a detail. In any case the question is a fine example of where the `java.time` classes are helpful.

Comment: @OleV.V. Certainly a good suggestion. The `compareTo` syntax is awkward and non-intuitive. Really though, the `Duration` should have comparison methods. Something like `isEqual`, `longerThan`, `shorterThan`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public class JavaApplication11 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -30);//Set Calendar 30 seconds in the past.

        System.out.println(has30SecsPassed(now));
    }

    static boolean has30SecsPassed(Calendar calendar)
    {
        Long numberOfMilliSec = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        double numberOfSecondsPassed = numberOfMilliSec / 1000.0;
        System.out.println("seconds passed: " + numberOfSecondsPassed);
        return numberOfSecondsPassed >= 30;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -secondsAgo);
long timeAgo = now.getTimeInMillis();
```

is too much overhead or just getting the actual time stamp in your app... you can just call

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and verify this condition between cooldown.get(id) and  timeAgo

so they meet **cooldown.get(id) - timeAgo < 30*1000** or not...

Answer (score 2):

To judge from [the code on Ideone that you link to](https://ideone.com/KLIIBz), the problem is that `secondsAgo` is 0, not 30. You set it to 30 in the constructor, but since you never create an object from the class, the constructor is never executed. `secondsAgo` is a static field, so you can access it without an object and without it having been initialized. You just get the initial value that all `int` fields have, namely 0.

The output I see in Ideone certainly confirms what I am saying. In all lines of the form `1491194338577 | 1491194338578` the numbers are either identical or just 1 millisecond apart. Even though you have subtracted `secondsAgo` seconds from the `Calendar` object that you get `timeAgo` from, `timeAgo` is never anywhere near 30 seconds earlier than the timestamp that you put into the map a millisecond ago. So no, you are not subtracting 30 seconds; you are subtracting 0 seconds.

That said I still agree with Basil Bourque’s answer: if there is any way you can use Java 8, you should throw the `Calendar` class away and use `Instant` and `Duration`. You get much clearer and more readable code. Put `Instant` objects in your map instead of `Long`s and it’s suddenly self-explanatory what they are.

Answer (score -3):

currentTimeMillis returns: the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

Can you explain why you use it.

Comment: I don't know. You tell me. Again. I am trying to store, and check a timestamp (whatever type of timestamp) to see if it is older than 30 seconds, or whatever I define, even minutes.

Many examples on SO use System.currentTimeMillis() for timestamps.

Please post an answer to the question rather than a question. This could be saved for a comment.

Comment: Asking for clarification should be in a comment. It is certainly not an answer. Wait until you have the required 50 rep for leaving comments. Until then, delete this answer to clear the negative rep I just gave it.